# Wordpress: when returning the history after unlogging it shows the Desktop

Tags: wordpress

I have the following problem: I made a site that works everything well but it is not approved by the security sector because when the user logs out and presses the back button of the browser history, he sees the content. I need that content not be seen, that when logging out the user does not see anything of the wp-admin folder by pressing the back button of the browser. The specific security request is: modify development so that when logging out, cookies and / or session token are eliminated so that the only way to return to the session is by logging in again. I already explained that cookies have been removed when logging out, but they consider that being able to go back and view content can expose sensitive information, such as user data and others ... Any help, more than welcome Thank you! PAto